# tabbar middle tab out of tabbar corner

Tags: ios, uikit, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I want to make a tab bar with 5 tab items. I want the middle one ( third ) to be out of tab bar's corner it may be tough to understand therefore I decided to add screenshot[image]

I want to make something like you can see above but I don't know how it's possible.
I would appreciate any way you recommend to do it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]select tabbar Item and set its image insets

Make sure to get proper image (if using an image) goto Assets-> select desired image -> set property to always original

Answer (score 0):

create a class of **UITabBarController** and assign it to the TabBarController.

initialise Variable

```
let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
```

Then in **viewDidLoad**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
       
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "IMAGE_NAME_FROM_ASSETS"), for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIStyle.Color.CameraBG
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 40
        button.addShadow(offset: CGSize(width: 5, height: 5), color: UIStyle.Color.CameraShadow, radius: 5, opacity: 0.1)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressedAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.insertSubview(button, aboveSubview: self.tabBar)
        
    }
```

Add **viewDidLayoutSubviews** in your class

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    // safe place to set the frame of button manually
    button.frame = CGRect.init(x: self.tabBar.center.x - 40, y: self.view.bounds.height - 100, width: 80, height: 80)
}
```

**Action** You Want To Perform on button click

```
@objc func pressedAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // do your stuff here
    let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: YOURVC.storyboardInstance())
    nc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(nc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```