# Tab Bar icons are not conforming to image insets

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to get the icons in the tab bar to be brought down more into the middle of the bar. I have tried setting the image insets in the story board as well as through code and none of it is working.

I'm currently using iOS 15 + Xcode 13.1.

EX: (top: 6, right: 0, bottom: -6, left: 0)

This is an example of the code I attempted as well:

```
tabBar.items?[0].imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 20, bottom: -6, right: 0)
```

This is a picture of the current state. You'll see that even without a title, all the icons float to the top of the bar and I want them to be aligned lower in the bar.
[image]

Comment: You can refer following link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70122162/tabbar-middle-tab-out-of-tabbar-corner/70122374#70122374

Comment: All the answer in the link says is to set image insets which is what isn't working for me...

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure but as far as I know there is no way to change it's alignment.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend modifying the native tab bar. If you definitely want to update the position of tab bar items I encourage you to use a custom tab bar. You will have a lot more control over how it behaves and you will avoid any hacky solution.